# Reorder cursor data

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Is there any way to load some data from sqlite cursor, and update existing column data with custom calculation and re-order cursor rows by that column in android studio? I do not want to commit new data to database.

Can anyone please point me in right direction to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this when extracting data using derived values from expressions and an approrpiate **ORDER BY** clause.

e.g. say you had columns in the table named x and y and they had numeric values then you could add a derived column z that would be accessible from the cursor :-

```
SELECT x,y, x * y AS z FROM your_table ORDER BY z
```

In android this could be assumng **db** is an instance of [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase).

```
Cursor your_cursor = db.query("your_table", new String[]{"x","y","x * y AS z"},null,null,null,null,"z");
```

See [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for an explanation of the parameters.

You could do this programatically with a Cursor extracted using just "SELECT * FROM your_table (`db.query("your_table,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);`) but you would have to build the result and then sort the resultant extract (simpler and likely more effecient to let SQLite do it for you).

The are others such as building a [MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor).

However, you cannot, using standard API's, reorder or change data in the Cursor itself as a Cursor is intended to be the result of a query of the database. It is also buffered so may access the database to retrive additional data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm having some complex algorithm to resolve and order data by that column in very limited time duration. I've tried to do the calculation withing query, but realized it's too much for sqlite with it's limited features. Writing to database and re querying takes much time for me. Building MatrixCursor for cursor data and order in java also takes much memory and processor time for me. Thanks anyway.